# Android Table Row Image dimension

Tags: android, image, row, android-tablelayout, dimension

I want to put one image on the beginning of each row in my application . The problem is, the image is too big and when I put it there, it occupies the whole screen.

main.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableView"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".90"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
            ></TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

This is how I add the image :

```
    TableLayout tableView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    ImageView im;
    im = new ImageView(this);
    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.rss);
    row.addView(im); 
    tableView.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I add the rows dynamically  so,  I want to add the image the same way.

PS: There is no change if I replace

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

with

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I would like to make the image much smaller. Could you help me out?

Comment: cant u use ScaleType for imageviews.?

Comment: try `im.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams(200, 400));` with ImageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the imageview this way..

```
im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP );
row.addView(im, new TableRow.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the aspect ratio of the imageview? what are the parameters

Comment: If you could help me again please  . I would like to make the image bigger , not the view. If I change the parameters , the image gets bigger until one point , when it stays the same , regardless the parameters .

Comment: I'll get a better idea if you put a snapshot. You can add this as a new question..

Comment: Well, this question was about the exact same thing , so there is no sense in asking another one . I just need to resize the image.

Comment: I dont understand. What do you mean by making the image bigger and not the view? Do you mean u want only a part of the image to be visible, like zoomed in? Or something else.

Comment: Try this `im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY );` Try other constants in `ScaleType` class and select the one which suits your needs

Comment: look , you see how [tiny](http://i55.tinypic.com/vcs5g7.jpg/) the images are ?  I want to make them bigger , to fill the whole [space](http://i52.tinypic.com/2v0zlua.jpg) . Yes , something like zoomed in would be fine , I just want a bigger image , not necessarily  a full one . If I change the parameters in `row.addView(im, new TableRow.LayoutParams(50, 50));` , the picture stays the same , the row dimension changes . Hope now you understand what I mean and you could help me . Thanks.

Comment: To make the image bigger, you can try setting the `scaleType` of `ImageView` as I said in my last comment.

Comment: Do I use `im.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY );` with `row.addView(im, new TableRow.LayoutParams(50, 50));` or just with `row.addView(im)` ? And what about the zoom in feature?

Comment: Here is link to doc of `ScaleType`. Have a look at all options. The most closest to your requirement is `CENTER_CROP`